# How to display a local image before webview is successfully loaded in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview

In Flutter, I would like to display a local image before my webview is loaded. In case the user hasn't turn on their wifi, an image will be shown instead of a blank white screen(ios) or an error message saying cannot connect to said webpage(android).

I am using the official webview_flutter package for this app.

Below is the code that I've tried, but it works on ios but doesn't work on android. In Android, when I turned off the wifi and launch the app, an error message which displays the webview link is shown.

Edit: Does not change from image to webview after wifi is connected and pressed the reload button.

```
final webViewKey1 = GlobalKey<WebViewContainerState>();
var _url = 'http://www.google.com';
final _key = UniqueKey();
bool _isLoadingPage;

class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewPageState createState() => WebViewPageState();
}

class WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 1'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: (){
            Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.refresh), 
            color: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              webViewKey1.currentState?.reloadWebView();
            },
          ),
        ]
      ),
      body: 
          WebViewContainer(key: webViewKey1),   
    );
  }
}

class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  WebViewContainer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  WebViewContainerState createState() => WebViewContainerState();
}

class WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  WebViewController _webViewController;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoadingPage = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Opacity(opacity: _isLoadingPage?0:1, child: WebView(
            key: _key,
            initialUrl: _url,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _webViewController = controller;
            },
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
              setState(() {
                _isLoadingPage = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          ),
          _isLoadingPage
            ? Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/fail.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            )
            : Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
        ],
      );
  }

  void reloadWebView() {
    _webViewController?.reload();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use opacity widget to make it invisible and on completion show it.

```
Opacity(opacity: _isLoadingPage?0:1, child: WebView(
          key: _key,
          initialUrl: _url,
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (webViewCreate) {
            _controller.complete(webViewCreate);
          },
          onPageFinished: (finish) {
            setState(() {
              _isLoadingPage = false;
            });
          },
        ),)
```

Comment: When I try to reload the webview when wifi is disconnected, the error message "Webpage not available" is still shown on Android, any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexedStack and switch between widget after WebView loaded using `onPageFinished`. You can use the `connectivity` plugin to check for connectivity.

```
ConnectivityResult _connectionStatus;
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _connectivitySubscription;
  int _page = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initConnectivity();
    _connectivitySubscription =
        _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_updateConnectionStatus);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _connectivitySubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initConnectivity() async {
    ConnectivityResult result;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      result = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

    // If the widget was removed from the tree while the asynchronous platform
    // message was in flight, we want to discard the reply rather than calling
    // setState to update our non-existent appearance.
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }

    _updateConnectionStatus(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_connectionStatus);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _page,
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
            onPageFinished: (_) {
              if (_connectionStatus != ConnectivityResult.none) {
                setState(() {
                  _page = 0;
                });
              }
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Some Image'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _updateConnectionStatus(ConnectivityResult result) async {
    switch (result) {
      case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
      case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
      case ConnectivityResult.none:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        break;
      default:
        setState(() => _connectionStatus = result);
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: When I try to reload the webview when wifi is disconnected, the error message "Webpage not available" is still shown on Android, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Here I'm checking the connectivity and updating the widget.

Comment: The image doesn't reload to show the webview when wifi is connected, even when I pressed the reload button, the image is stuck and doesn't show webview, any idea why that's happening?

Comment: Code is in the edit, I've tried your method, but it shows the image when I launch the app even when wifi is connected

Answer (score 0):

You can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), that has a lot of events, including events to manage errors (such as net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE) while the WebView is loading an url (`onLoadError` event) and when it receives HTTP errors, such as 403, 404, etc (`onLoadHttpError` event).

You can use the [connectivity](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) plugin to listen for network state changes by subscribing to the stream exposed by connectivity plugin.

Also, you can use IndexedStack and switch between widgets after the WebView is loaded using `onLoadStop`.

Full example:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  int _page = 2;
  bool _loadError = false;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result != ConnectivityResult.none && webView != null) {
        print("reload");
        _loadError = false;
        webView.reload();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _page,
          children: <Widget>[
            InAppWebView(
              initialUrl: "https://flutter.dev",
              initialHeaders: {},
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                  inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                    clearCache: true,
                    debuggingEnabled: true,
                  ),
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                webView = controller;
              },
              onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

              },
              onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                print(url);
                setState(() {
                  if (!_loadError) {
                    _page = 0;
                  } else {
                    _page = 1;
                  }
                });
              },
              onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, int code, String message) async {
                print("error $url: $code, $message");
                _loadError = true;
              },
              onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url, int statusCode, String description) async {
                print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
              },
            ),
            (Platform.isAndroid) ? Container(
                child: Text("My custom error message"),
            ) : Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/fail.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/loading.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```